# Amazon Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to ask alexa different sorts of questions and then at the end I want it should ask "Is there anything else you would like to know?" and when I say yes (where yes is working suggestion) it should suggest me according to the intent I am  in. Like if I am in

```
IncityIntent:

    'InCityIntent': function () {
        speechOutput = '';


speechOutput = "The atmosphere in the city is beautiful. Is there anything else you would like to know";
        this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, speechOutput);


'YesIntent': function () {
        speechOutput = '';
/*when the user say yes, he should get this output*/  
            speechOutput = You can learn more about city by trying, alexa what are the best places in the city";
            this.emit(":tell",speechOutput, speechOutput);

FoodIntent:

    'FoodIntent': function () {
        speechOutput = '';


speechOutput = "Food in the city is delicious. Is there anything else you would like to know";
        this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, speechOutput);

'YesIntent': function () {
        speechOutput = '';
/*change in response here*/
            speechOutput = You can learn more about food by trying, alexa what are the best restaurants in the city";
            this.emit(":tell",speechOutput, speechOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, do not create custom `YesIntent` and `NoIntent`, instead use `AMAZON.YesIntent` and `AMAZON.NoIntent`. You can always add utterences to these predefined intents if you want to.

Your issues can be solved in a couple of ways.

**Using sessionAttributes**:
Add a `previousIntent` attribute  or something to keep a track of the converstation in the `sessionAttributes` when you receive the initial request, say `InCityIntent`. And in your `AMAZON.YesIntent` or `AMAZON.NoIntent` handler check for the previous intent and reply accordingly.

```
 'InCityIntent': function () {
       const speechOutput = "The atmosphere in the city is beautiful. Is there anything else you would like to know";
       const reprompt = "Is there anything else you would like to know";
       this.attributes['previousIntent'] = "InCityIntent";
       this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, reprompt);
  }

 'Amazon.YesIntent': function () {
     var speechOutput =  "";
     var reprompt = "";
     if (this.attributes 
        && this.attributes.previousIntent
        && this.attributes.previousIntent === 'InCityIntent' ) {
        speechOutput = "You can learn more about city by trying, Alexa what are the best places in the city";
        reprompt = "your reprompt";
     } else if ( //check for FoodIntent ) {

       // do accordingly
     }
     this.attributes['previousIntent'] = "Amazon.YesIntent";
     this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, reprompt);
  }
```

**Using STATE handlers**
`ask-nodejs-sdk` v1 has state handlers to generate response based on states. The idea is similar, the sdk will add the `sessionAttribute` parameter for you and the when will automatically map the handler with respect to that state.

```
 'InCityIntent': function () {
       const speechOutput = "The atmosphere in the city is beautiful. Is there anything else you would like to know";
       const reprompt = "Is there anything else you would like to know";
       this.handler.state = "ANYTHING_ELSE";
       this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, reprompt);
  }

const stateHandlers = Alexa.CreateStateHandler("ANYTHING_ELSE", {
    "AMAZON.YesIntent": function () {
       var speechOutput =  "You can learn more about city by trying, Alexa what are the best places in the city";
       var reprompt = "your reprompt";
       this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, reprompt);
    },
```

Once a `state` is set, then next time the the intent handlers defined in that particular state handler will be triggered. Change your `state` accordingly and once done, remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but none of the above worked. It gives error as no response.

Comment: do not copy paste the code, take it as just a reference.

Comment: I didn't copy paste. When I am try to run this code and if I say yes with my skill name like tell citytravel yes then it repeats the dialog from intent where I have declared yes first time and if I just say yes then it says as There was a problem with the requested skill's response.

Comment: Once you are in a skill session, you don't have to use skill invocation name everytime.