# Alexa YESNO Intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I had asked this question before also but no luck, so I am posting again. I am working on amazon alexa skill and I want that when I call 'YESNOIntent' it should answer differently under different Intents.

```
'FirstIntent': function () {
speechoutput = 'bla bla, would you like to know anything else?'
this.emit(":ask", speechOutput)
},

'YESNOIntent': function (){
speechoutput = 'speech1'
this.emit(":ask", speechOutput)
},

'SecondIntent': function () {
speechoutput = 'bla bla, would you like to know anything else?'
this.emit(":ask", speechOutput)
},

'YESNOIntent': function (){
speechoutput = 'speech2'
this.emit(":ask", speechOutput)
},

'ThirdIntent': function () {
speechoutput = 'bla bla, would you like to know anything else?'
this.emit(":ask", speechOutput)
},

'YESNOIntent': function (){
speechoutput = 'speech3'
this.emit(":ask", speechOutput)
},
```

...... so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon Alexa Skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52077201/amazon-alexa-skill)

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for your response, actually the previous question was also posted by me but the suggestion on the didn't work out for me.

Comment: So you [edit] your first question with what you've learned. I see no progression here, so it shouldn't be a new question.

Comment: yes it's the same as previous questoin, but as you see I didn't get the desired result so I thought to post the question in more detailed way and easily understandable format.

Answer (score 2):

**YES** and **NO** are two different things. You cannot merge these two into a single `YesNoIntent`. As I said in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078612/1574023) you should use `AMAZON.YesIntent` and `AMAZON.NoIntent`.

Make use of `sessionAttributes` to keep track of *"where you are with respect to the conversation"* so that you can give a correct response when `AMAZON.YesIntent` or `AMAZON.NoIntent` handlers are triggered.

Comment: Thanks, I am using AMAZON.YesIntent and AMAZON.NoIntent separately, sorry I mentioned it together here by mistake. Will it be possible for you to explain it through my code?